# Fixing width of text from file.write

Tags: ruby, text

I am trying to fix the width of the written text going to my .txt file.

Currently the values are collected through a gets command from user input. Then they are passed through a class object and assigned to various `@___` variables. Then called under a `Grade_Log.new(add_class, add_assignment, add_grade)`. And eventually written individually to the .txt file.

```
class Grade_Log
  attr_accessor :which_class, :assignment_type, :grade

  def initialize(which_class, assignment_type, grade)
    @which_class = which_class
    @assignment_type = assignment_type
    @grade = grade
  end

  def attribute_class
    @which_class
  end

  def attribute_assignment
    @assignment_type
  end

  def attribute_grade
    @grade
  end
end

input = Grade_Log.new(add_class, add_assignment, add_grade)

File.open("grade_log.txt", "a") do |file|
  file.write(input.attribute_class)
  file.write(" ")
  file.write(input.attribute_assignment)
  file.write(" ")
  file.write(input.attribute_grade)
  file.write("\n")
end
```

I am getting the output that I am intending to get... "`PHYSICS HOMEWORK 97`" however, I would like for the spacing to be fixed at 20 width for each variable so I don't have to manually insert the " ".

Comment: I cleaned up the whitespace in your code sample. As a style note, [you should use CamelCase](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#camelcase-classes) for class names. (so `GradeLog`, not `Grade_Log`)

Comment: Could you provide an example of the sort of output you'd expect?

Comment: [`String#ljust`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-ljust) or [`String#rjust`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-rjust) depending on your preference for alignment